# Square-connect. Square-checkout collect phone number

Tags: square-connect, square-checkout

I am working with the square-connect API to take payments on my site. Using checkout I can collect the name, address, and email of the customer. Is there possibly a way to configure the checkout page to also collect the customers phone number? I see no reference to that in the documentation, but is there a way to do this?

As a side note I am using the node.js version of the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently with the Checkout API when ask_for_shipping_address is set to true it doesn't request the phone number of the customer. If you are using the Orders API to build an order you can use the Customers API to collect the customer information you need and add the customer_id to the order so it is retrievable.